# cure for mirror movements

Tags: hand, orthopedics

I am 15 years old. i exhibit mirror movements in respect to my hands. when i move my right hand my left hand automatically moves and vice versa. is there any cure for these movements? whilst doing any work it may be an obstruction or twice of my energy would be spent.